Can't recall this action movie against aliens
I'm currently looking for the name of a movie, where it was war with a lot of aliens, and a war commander (I guess) was enrolled to fight. But when dying on the battlefield, some "alien juice" got into his mouth and he resurrected, and everytime he would die, he would resurrect outside the basements with a black guy shouting at him and shoving him.
It's a recent movie, I hope you'll have some clues on what it is.

Edge of Tomorrow with Tom Cruise from 2014.

A military officer is brought into an alien war against an extraterrestrial enemy who can reset the day and know the future. When this officer is enabled with the same power, he teams up with a Special Forces warrior to try and end the war.





Thanks a lot! I couldn't find it, and I swear I tried. ^^

The movie also had a tag line, "Live, Die, Repeat" which was so extremely, prominently displayed that I thought it WAS the title. Maybe that played a part in not being able to remember it.

@Smithers -- In some markets, Live, Die, Repeat was the title.
